# Server-side error when redirecting to same page on form submission

Tags: c#

Everything worked fine on localhost, but as soon as I uploaded my website to the server, every form on my site throws a 404 error when I redirect after form submission -- why?

Code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        getContent();
    }
}

public void getContent()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["pageID"]))
    {
        int _pageID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["pageID"]);
        DataRow dr = objMenu.getMenuByID(_pageID);
        _str.Append("<div class='page-head'>");
        _str.Append("<h1>" + dr["name"] + "</h1>");
        _str.Append("<p>" + dr["content"].ToString().Replace("\r\n", "<br/>") + "</p>");
        _str.Append("</div>");
        litOutput.Text = _str.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
    }
}

public void createMail()
{
    string mail = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("dist/mail/support-besked.html"));
    mail = mail.Replace("#name#", txtNavn.Text);
    objTools.SendEmail(txtMail.Text, "", mail);
}

protected void btnContact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    objContact.addContact(txtNavn.Text, txtAdresse.Text, txtMail.Text, txtTelefon.Text, txtBesked.Text);
    createMail();   
    litStatus.Text += "<div class='success-box'><i class='fa fa-check-circle' aria-hidden='true'></i><span>Vi har modtaget din besked og kommer til dig snarest muligt.</span></div>";
    Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "5;URL=Contact.aspx");
}
```

Error handling:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/500.aspx">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx"/>
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/500.aspx"/>
</customErrors>

<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
        <remove statusCode="404"/>
        <error statusCode="404" path="404.html" responseMode="File"/>
        <remove statusCode="500"/>
        <error statusCode="500" path="500.html" responseMode="File"/>
</httpErrors>
```

Is it my error handling I have done wrong, or am I doing something I shouldn't?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that all the error pages actually exist? I see redirects for `404.aspx` and `404.html` in there.

Comment: Also, temporarily removing the error redirects in the config file may help you figure out the problem.

Comment: Tried out commenting errror handling, than i get an error message saying. That i should add customErrors to my webconfig...

Comment: OK. It sounds like you are encountering an error. You need to set `customErrors` mode to `Off` so it shows you details about the problem. It looks like the `500` redirect is not working. Do you actually have a `~/500.aspx` page?

Comment: Okay, setting it to off helped, it was my SendMail() function.

Comment: The custom errors were masking the real issue and I am glad you figured that out. However, you still have a problem with your redirects. I think `~/500.aspx` does not exist at the root of the application. As a side note and general rule, consider adding logging to your application so you can see what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice. 500.aspx do exist, but how would i add logging to my application?

Comment: Various ways. Google it and you will find plenty of tutorials.